# Float.parse of string number result in a another number in the DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, casting, floating-point

Why when I float.Parse a string "109.7" and insert the result into the DB to a 'float' column I get 109.69999694824219 instead of 109.7?

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and C#. The string of the number is taken from a Text input field.

Comment: see, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

floats do not have full precision.  You should use decimal.Parse instead.

Comment: But my DB column is set to float data type. Do I need to change it to decimal instead of float - I mean for the DB column?

or like this: float width = (float)decimal.Parse(w)

Comment: Well then you will need to round the number when you pull it out of the database or change the type in the database to a decimal.

Comment: If you need precision, then your column has the wrong data type. ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ALTER COLUMN MyColumn decimal(18,2)  With a scale and precision that makes sense for your application

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the column to Decimal